# WPF UserControl binding failure

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I've stumbled upon a problem and hope someone would be able to give me a hand in tackling it.

I have an assembly with a few UserControls. I'd like to load a UserControl from that *external* assembly at runtime (and take a screenshot of it later on without showing it on the screen).

**The UserControl xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyAssembly.Test"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="TD1"
                Height="30"
                Width="100"
                Content="{Binding ABC}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**The "view model"**

```cs
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _abc = "Initial value";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string ABC
    {
        get
        {
            return _abc;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _abc)
            {
                return;
            }
            _abc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged1("ABC");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged1(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**The piece of code that causes headaches**

```cs
Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll");
var uri = new Uri(@"/MyAssembly;component/Test.xaml"), UriKind.Relative);
var view = (Control)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
view.Width = 800;
view.Height = 600;
view.RenderSize = new Size(800, 600);
view.Background = Brushes.White;

var viewModel = new TestClass();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
viewModel.ABC = "7";
```

However neither on setting DataContext, nor on changing ABC property TD1 Content is changing. It always stays null (if I look at it with a debugger).

How to force .Net to do binding (of ABC in this example) according to xaml loaded from external assembly?

Comment: Does it work with just a <TextBox Text="{Binding ABC}"/>

Comment: @nbulba is it standard `Button` with default template? If no and you set `Content="ABC"` does it display _ABC_?

Comment: @dkozl Yes, if I leave Content="ABC" it works as expected since no binding actually involved. Yes, it is a standard Button.

Comment: @Blam No, it does not work with just a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found the way make bindings work. All one needs to do is to call `UpdateLayout` on the view.

```cs
Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll");
var uri = new Uri(@"/MyAssembly;component/Test.xaml"), UriKind.Relative);
var view = (Control)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
view.Width = 800;
view.Height = 600;
view.RenderSize = new Size(800, 600);
view.Background = Brushes.White;

var viewModel = new TestClass();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
viewModel.ABC = "7";

view.UpdateLayout();
```